# Is the converter operating under continuous mode of conduction?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

The switch, S of the DC to DC Buck converter shown in the figure is operated with a duty cycle of 0.5 at a switching frequency of 5 kHz while it is feeding a certain load.

While the input voltage of the converter is maintained at 100 V dc, the steady state average voltage at the output terminals of the converter, Vo is found to be 30.

Is the converter operating under continuous mode of conduction ?

[image] V.

Comment: Wasn't this question asked a couple of weeks ago except Vo was said to be 70V. Are you resitting your exam?

Comment: Yup, here it is http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62274/is-the-converter-operating-under-discontinuous-mode-of-conduction?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

No, because at that duty cycle you'd expect 50V output at D=0.5, so clearly the output capacitor is dropping in voltage due to reversing current flow in the inductor.

Comment: I think it is in continuous mode: at 50:50 duty cycle it is unable to push enough energy through the inductor due to the load resistance being too low; the inductor will always be conducting current in the direction of the load (or am i being stupid again)

Comment: No the current in the inductor cannot reverse itself, there's no place for it to go. Neither the diode nor the transistor (switch) will pass current in that direction. The reason the output voltage drops is that the inductor does not reach a peak current during the "on" part of the cycle that can sustain the current throughout the rest of the cycle.